# Unable to set timezone in Highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts, timezone, momentjs

I want to set timezone 'America/Los_Angeles' in the Highchart graph and i dont want to show default client browser timezone. For that i have added library moment.js into code. But when i am running this, i am getting below error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.tz is not a function
    at a.Time.getTimezoneOffset (highstock.js:97)
    at a.Time.timezoneOffset.set (highstock.js:95)
    at a.Time.getTimeTicks (highstock.js:99)
    at F.C.getTimeTicks (highstock.js:166)
    at F.<anonymous> (highstock.js:393)
    at F.a.(anonymous function) [as getTimeTicks] (https://url/highstock-6.0.5/highstock.js:19:376)
    at F.setTickPositions (highstock.js:139)
    at F.<anonymous> (highstock.js:404)
    at F.a.(anonymous function) [as setTickPositions] (https://url/highstock-6.0.5/highstock.js:19:376)
    at F.setTickInterval (highstock.js:138)
```

Following are the Highchart graph code which i am using

```
window.moment = moment;    

Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'area',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
          time: {
                    timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'graph'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                            'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Attack Size'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                         return  Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %H:%M',new Date(this.x))+ '<br/> Attack <b>' + this.y + ' ]';
                   } 
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                  },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                    pointStart: 1940,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series:{
                        turboThreshold:4000
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Description',
                    data: data
                }]
            });
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vk97rsnp/1/. That said, this: `pointStart: 1940,` does not mean what you think it means for a datetime axis. setting `pointStart` to `1940` means that the point starts at `1.940 seconds` after `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. If you wanted the year 1940 it would be better to do: `Date.UTC(1940)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `.tz is not a function` means that the the `tz` function is not available on the `moment` object, probably because [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone) has not been installed.

You will need to import both `moment.js` and `moment-timezone-with-data` (or `moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2020`, etc.) as described in [the moment-timezone docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).